# ngx-datatable - CRUD with reactive forms

Tags: angular, datatable, crud, angular-reactive-forms, ngx-datatable

I'm trying to create a CRUD table (rows from a http service) with the angular module ngx-datatable.

I want to use reactive forms to accomplish this (newbie). The problem is that ngx-datatable doesn't have a row-template to where I could bind a formgroup for each row. Also I have a filter (with ngModel) for each column in the header template.

So basically I want to achieve this table (ng2-smart-table) but with ngx-datatable:

[image]

Currently I have no clue how I can get this done, as the docs are really poor and there is no row template which holds the row index for a potential formgroup.